# Wonder about definition of negligible set

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I've read "Probability and Measure" in page 8 and encounter definition of negligible set:

> Define a subset $ A $ of $ \Omega $ to be *negligible* if for each positive $ \epsilon $ there exists a finite or countable collection $ I _ 1 , I _ 2 , \dots $ of intervals (they may overlap) satisfying
> $$ A \subset \bigcup _ k I _ k $$
> and
> $$ \sum _ k | I _ k | < \epsilon \text . $$
> A negligible set is one that can be covered by intervals the total sum of whose lengths can be made arbitrarily small.

I wonder about symbol $ | I _ k | $ in the definition. Whether it is number of elements in $ I _ k $? Could anyone help me?

Comment: I think it means length of $I_k$. E.g. $|(a,b)|=b-a$.

Comment: It denotes the length of the interval $I_k$. In $\mathbb{R}$, every interval is of the form $(a,b)$, $[a,b)$, $(a,b]$ or $[a,b]$, but they all have length $b-a$ (if $b\geq a$, in general the length writes $|b-a|$)

Comment: @nejimban Ik is countable or finite, so I don't think | | is length of Ik!

Comment: @minhquýlê - $I_k$ is not countable - it is an uncountable subset of the reals.  But as an interval covering part of a negligible set, its length is finite and in the words of your question such lengths "can be made arbitrarily small"

Comment: @minhquýlê Nejimban is exactly right. Length is not cardinality.

Comment: @Henry so " exists a finite or countable collection I1,I2,… of intervals" is for the number of Ik not about countable of Ik, right?

Comment: @nejimban so each $Ik$ has form [a,a]?

Comment: @minhquýlê I’d guess so, in measure theory $|\cdot|$ usually denotes Lebesgue measure. Anyway it should be explained what $|\cdot|$ and $\Omega$  mean in the previous pages…

Comment: @minhquýlê It says "finite or countable COLLECTION", the number of intervals is finite or countable.

Comment: Given $\epsilon$, you do not need to have the $I_k$ to be single points of the form $[a,a]$.  You could have them of the form $[a,a+2^{-k-2}\epsilon]$ so their lengths add up to less than $\epsilon$